# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint when inserting rows in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to insert some rows into my table 'Quiz'. When my table is empty and i try to insert the first row it works but whenever i try to enter a second row i keep getting this error :

`Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Quiz__D0C4726C5B2346B6'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Quiz'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>).`

I dont really have an idea whats causing it since i always enter different Id's for each row.

Presentation Layer:

```
if (IsValidData())
{
    quiz.QuizID = Convert.ToInt32(quizIDTextBox.Text);               
    quiz.QuizNaam = quizNaamTextBox.Text;
    quiz.QuizDatum = Convert.ToString(quizDatumDateTimePicker.Text);
    quiz.Locatie = locatieTextBox.Text;
    quiz.Type = typeTextBox.Text;
    quiz.Moeilijkheidsgraad = moeilijkheidsgraadTextBox.Text;

    QuizDB.InsertQuiz(quiz);
    MessageBox.Show("Quiz Toegevoegd", "Quiz");
}
```

DataBase Layer:

```
public static void InsertQuiz(Quiz quiz)
{

    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Quiz (QuizID,QuizNaam,QuizDatum,Locatie,Type,Moeilijkheidsgraad) VALUES (@QuizID,@QuizNaam, @QuizDatum, @Locatie, @Type, @Moeilijkheidsgraad)";

    SqlCommand quizCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, conn);
    quizCommand.Parameters.Clear();

    quizCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizID", quiz.QuizID);
    quizCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizNaam", quiz.QuizNaam);
    quizCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizDatum", quiz.QuizDatum);
    quizCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locatie", quiz.Locatie);
    quizCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", quiz.Type);
    quizCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Moeilijkheidsgraad",quiz.Moeilijkheidsgraad);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        quizCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Bussiness Layer :

```
public class Quiz
{
    private int cQuizId;
    private string cQuizNaam;
    private string cQuizDatum;
    private int cWinnaarId;
    private string cLocatie;
    private string cType;
    private string cMoeilijkheidsgraad;

    public Quiz() { }

    public int QuizID
    {
        get { return cQuizId;}
        set { cQuizId = value; }
    }

    public string QuizNaam
    {
        get { return cQuizNaam; }
        set { cQuizNaam = value; }
    }
    public string QuizDatum
    {
        get { return cQuizDatum; }
        set { cQuizDatum = value; }
    }

    public int WinnaarId
    {
        get { return cWinnaarId; }
        set { cWinnaarId = value; }
    }

    public string Locatie
    {
        get { return cLocatie; }
        set { cLocatie = value; }
    }
    public string Type
    {
        get { return cType; }
        set { cType = value; }
    }
    public string Moeilijkheidsgraad
    {
        get { return cMoeilijkheidsgraad; }
        set { cMoeilijkheidsgraad = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have a uniqueness constraint on the `Quiz` table. Have you tried inserting the same values manually into your table?

Comment: Is the first id you insert ok? Is it an integer?

Comment: Do you have checked, after the first insert, if any column value is NULL? Perhaps it brings to you some hints to find the problem...

Comment: Set your `QuizID` as Key and make it Auto incremented id and then you don't need to insert it from the code. DB will look after you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Convert, use TryParse instead, that's safer. Also, getters and setters can be simply written as:

```
public string QuizNaam { get; set; }
```

Now for your question, what are you using as your primary key in your database? It sounds more like something on your DB end and not your code.

Comment: My primary key is 'QuizId' with datatype set to int

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason for using a user input as the primary key I would suggest having the DB generated it itself. This is likely the reason for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_*Quiz*_D0C4726C5B2346B6'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Quiz'. The duplicate key
>   value is `(<NULL>)`.

According to the error message it seems your code does'nt provide the Id as expected but leave it empty (null), and your database allows null values in the Id column (which is not a good practice), so the first insert works fine but then the second time you try to insert null into the table it detects a dataset with null and you get this exception.

Why dont you use a serial sequence on this column? you can let your database do this, take alook at a [database sequence (MSSQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that `QuizID` is the primary key of your table.)

Please check to make sure that `quiz.QuizID` in your database layer is not `Null` or empty.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need special meaningful ID.

set **QuizID** field as Primary Key with [Identity increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379250/cant-set-auto-increment-via-sql-server-express-management-studio) then You don't need to insert it.